# SWIFT - JSON "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead."

Tags: ios, json, swift

i have problem with my json response

When I use this func , I print all data corect

```
      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(jsonString)
            }
        }
    } .resume()
```

i get this correct data:

> "brand":"Lamborghini",
> "model":"Huracan",
> "color":"#0052ff"
> ,"registration":"K1TEST",
> "lat":50.244495,
> "lng":18.996143,

but when i am using JasonDecoder and Model struct

```
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let carData = try decoder.decode([Model].self, from: data)
            print(carData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } .resume()
```

Model:

```
struct Model : Codable {
let brand : String
let model : String
let color : String
let registration : String
let lat : Double
let lng : Double }
```

> CodingKeys(stringValue: "lat", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead."

I know that this is something wrong whit lat and lng data but i don't know how to fix it.
Help

Comment: the json you show as "..correct data:..." is `Model`, but you decode `[Model]`. So change that to `Model`, unless what you show is not what you say you get.

Comment: I agree, even if you only include part of the json you get that part should still be included as correct json to avoid confusion.

Comment: valid json  array of dicionary - [Model] is correct

Comment: could you add `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` just after `guard let data....`, and show us what it prints.

Comment: Optional("[\n {\"_id\":\"5e5e40c4c0ea272d00000956\",\"brand\":\"Opel\",\"model\":\"Astra\",\"color\":\"#0fc0fc\",\"registration\":\"WA12345\",\"year\":\"2005-01-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"ownerId\":\"5e5e3d7fc0ea272d00000824\",\"lat\":50.754,\"lng\":12.2145,\"_recent_changed\":true},\n {\"_id\":\"5e5e3f32c0ea272d000008b5\",\"year\":\"2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"lat\":-55.42,\"lng\":-45.21,\"color\":\"#98eb61\",\"_mock\":true,\"_recent\":false,\"registration\":\"WA72ZH\",\"brand\":\"Audi\",\"model\":\"A3\",\"ownerId\":\"5e5e3d7fc0ea272d00000821\"},\n

Comment: i know what is wrong - one of respond look like this:  {
    "_id": "620d016e3abd1945001a5304",
    "brand": "Ford",
    "model": "Mustang GT",
    "color": "#000000",
    "registration": "WZ1233213",
    **"lat": "12.234243",**
   ** "lng": "12.004444",**
    "ownerId": "Martha Kowal",
    "year": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you have identified, where `lat` and `lng` can be `Double` and sometimes `String`,
can be dealt with the following code, to decode `lat` and `lng` into a consistent `Double`.

```
struct Model : Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    let id: String  // <-- an id is very useful in SwiftUI code
    let brand : String
    let model : String
    let color : String
    let registration : String
    let lat : Double
    let lng : Double
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case brand,model,color,registration,lat,lng
        case id = "_id"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        brand = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .brand)
        model = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .model)
        color = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .color)
        registration = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .registration)
        
        // decode lat, when it comes as a String
        if let theString = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lat),
            let latitude = Double(theString) {
            lat = latitude
        } else {
            lat = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .lat)
        }
        
        // decode lng, when it comes as a String
        if let theString = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lng),
            let longitude = Double(theString) {
            lng = longitude
        } else {
            lng = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .lng)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let lat : String
```

try this. from the error itself we can understand that you are getting lat as string and you are trying to parse as to double. I think the same thing will happen for lng also, so try to parse accordingly

Comment: I tried this before - CodingKeys(stringValue: "lat", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: can you please post the response as it is